# Loopback - validation before remote

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

Loopback validates data when saving data to the model. I am manipulating the data before saving in the remote method and I am getting 500 because the field is not present but I am using `validatesPresenceOf()` on the field.

```
module.exports = function(Otp) {
  Otp.validatesPresenceOf('number', {
    message: 'Phone number is required',
  });

  Otp.send = function(number, cb) {
    // Getting 500 here because number is null
    if (number.toString().length === 10) {
      number = '1' + number;
    }

    // Loopback is validating number here
    Otp.create({
      number: number
    });
  });
}
```

How do I validate the presence of `number` before the remote method is ever getting called?

I could check for the presence in the remote field itself, but I want to use loopback's built in validations

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the builtin validation but You can use beforeRemote hook as defined here [as described here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html#signature)

```
Otp.beforeRemote( "send", function( ctx, next) {
    // put your custom validation here
    if(!ctx.args.number){
       return next("Your Error")
    }
    next();
});
```

Comment: But if you use beforeRemote(), can you send the response format just like how loopback validator sends?

Comment: yes, you can also use your custom error format using `new Error` [(Doc Link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) instead of next("Your Error")